# Ribbon disappears after Save vsto Excel

Tags: vsto

I developed a VSTO project contains a ribbon, I saved the Excel file with the extension xlsm.
The problem is that I did not find my ribbon when I opened the xlsm file.

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Is it a document-level customization? Did you publish it somewhere? Did you save it to a trusted location?

Comment: What do you mean by document level customization?
I deployed the project with click once and when I open a new Excel I find my ribbon.
The problem is when I register with the extension xlsm I can not find it
I added it in the zone of confidence with:
File> Options> Click Trust Center> Trust Center Settings> Trusted Locations

Comment: I solved my problem.
it's about trusted location blocked company thank you :)

Comment: I saved my Excel file under xlsm because my file contains a macro that references my vsto project.

when i share my excel file in the network directory and run this macro i have an error because i do not have the vsto sources on the network.

Do you have any solutions please?

Comment: That's not an error I've ever seen or a use case I have experience with. You can try asking another question with the exact error message. But you should also list the steps you've taken to resolve it yourself if you do that.